# Oracle Sql tuning with index

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-performance

I have a table T with some 500000 records. That table is a hierarchical table. 
My goal is to update the table by self joining the same table based on some condition for parent - child relationship
The update query is taking really long because the number of rows is really high. I have created an unique index on the column which helps identifying the rows to update (meanign x and Y). After creating the index the cost has reduced but still the query is performing a lot slower.

This my query format

```
update T
set a1, b1
= (select T.parent.a1, T.parent.b1
 from T T.paremt, T T.child
where T.parent.id = T.child.Parent_id
and T.X = T.child.X
and T.Y = T.child.Y
```

after creating the index the execution plan shows that it is doing an index scan for CRS.PARENT but going for a full table scan for for CRS.CHILD and also during update as a result the query is taking for ever to complete.

Please suggest any tips or recommendations to solve this problem

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR update T ....(resto uf your query)....`, then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )`, then copy a result of last query (as a text!!!-  not bitmap!!!) and append it to the question. More on explain plan command you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#PFGRF009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are updating all 500,000 rows, so an index is a bad idea.  500,000 index lookups will take much longer than it needs to.

You would be better served using a `MERGE` statement.

It is hard to tell exactly what your table structure is, but it would look something like this, assuming X and Y are the primary key columns in T (...could be wrong about that):

```
MERGE INTO T
USING ( SELECT  TC.X,
                TC.Y,
                TP.A1,
                TP.A2 
        FROM    T TC 
        INNER JOIN T TP ON TP.ID = TC.PARENT_ID ) U
ON ( T.X = U.X AND T.Y = U.Y )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.A1 = U.A1, 
                             T.A2 = U.A2;
```

Comment: If you are updating all 500,000, it's probably even better to re-create the table, and do INSERT... AS SELECT...

Comment: @BobC You might be right, but updating two columns in a 500k row table shouldn't take too long.  I don't think I would introduce the complexity of DDL into this process unless I _really_ needed to maximize the performance.

Comment: The question as posted was about performance, which is my area of expertise. You are right that performing an update might be "good enough", but I wanted to at least show that excellent performance can be achieved. The DDL/DML will not be that complex. However it opens up the possibility of direct path load (via the APPEND hint) and parallelism. Doing a transformation vs modification with direct path load will also eliminate most of the overhead of undo and redo. Again, I just want readers of the post to understand what is possible.

Comment: @BobC Fair enough.  But to be clear, it also introduces at least a short window during which the data will be unavailable.  Unless you intend to delete instead of truncate, in which case you lose most, if not all, of the performance benefits.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. And of course, that needs to be considered. But if you can take an "unavailability window" of say 60 seconds, vs an update that takes 10 mins, what would you pick?

Comment: @BobC I know you're aware of the window.  But since you posted the comment for the benefit of the OP, I just thought it good that the OP be made aware of that aspect as well.  You're completely right: it is sometimes faster to recreate a table from scratch than to update every record, and sometimes its worth doing that even though it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Matthew McPeak,, thank you for understanding the question and providing the best solution.